# App on iphone 5 failed to install using itunes

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development. I know that in order to make apps for ios devices either you need to have developer account or jailbreak ios device. I jailbroke my iphone 5. Then I made simple hello world app for iphone and then converted it to .ipa. Now when I install it via itunes, I first see icon on my iphone and see that it is installing. After completion, it pops up a message that `app failed to install`. How can I fix this problem? Why its not installing?

Comment: Check the device log, usually it provides detailed messages for errors  during installation via iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/12/26/build-ipa-file-using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/

Try it it will help full , you can directly run app on your device